# OpenLayers.Control.ZoomPanel and slider

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to create a slider in `OpenLayers.Control.ZoomPanel` without using `OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar`?

I mean create a slider in zoompanel.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, you need to adapt it to your code:

```
map: map,
extent: OpenLayers.Bounds.fromString("-81,-10,-76,-14", false).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject()),
items: [{
xtype: "gx_zoomslider",
aggressive: true,
vertical: true,
height: 100,
x: 10,
y: 20,
plugins: new GeoExt.ZoomSliderTip({
template: "Scale: 1 : {scale}<br>Resolution: {resolution}"
})
}],
```

Hope this helps,